# using React - Axios to deliver mgs/mail with PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I am redoing my current portfolio from html to React based. So my contact form is backed by PHP, of which I am using mail function to send email using hostinger email accounts, which was fine.

Now, to achieve the same result with React, I've read many articles that pointed me to axios, now everytime I hit that submit button I am seeing a 404 error, can't understand where am I doing wrong.

Here's my App component -

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        fname: "", 
        name: "", 
        email: "", 
        message: "", 
        mailSent: false,
        error: null
    };

onFormSubmitSuccess = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/contact/',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: this.state
    })
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                mailSent: result.data.sent
            })
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>Contact Me</p>
            <div>
                <form action="#">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.."
                        value={this.state.fname}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ fname: e.target.value })}
                    />

                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.."
                        value={this.state.lname}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ lname: e.target.value })}
                    />

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                    />

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something.."
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
                        value={this.state.message}
                    ></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.onFormSubmitSuccess(e)} value="Submit" />
                    <div>
                        {this.state.mailSent &&
                            <div className="sucsess">Thank you for contcting me.</div>
                        }
                        {this.state.error &&
                            <div className="error">{this.state.error}</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my PHP file -

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");

$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

if (empty($_POST['fname']) && empty($_POST['email'])) {
print '<br/><b style="color:#B60000">Exception:</b> ';
echo "<br/><b>All fields are required. Please fill all the fields.</b>";
die();
}

//if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if ($_POST) {
http_response_code(200);

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mx1.hostinger.com';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '<email>';                    // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '<password>';                 // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'true';                         // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                  // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('fakeuser@domain.com', $name);
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('targetemail@gmail.com');         // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

$bodyContent = "<html>\n";
$bodyContent .= "<head>\n";
$bodyContent .= "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal' rel='stylesheet'>\n";
$bodyContent .= "</head>\n";
$bodyContent .= "<body style=\"font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; font-size: 1em; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; color: #4B4B4B;\">\n";
$bodyContent .= "<br/> Hello Admin!<br/><br/> PFB feedback from '$name'.<br/><br/>\n";
$bodyContent .= "Email ID: $email <br/> Message: $message <br/>\n";
$bodyContent .= "</body>\n";
$bodyContent .= "</html>\n";


$mail->Subject = 'Feedback - IKwizU';
$mail->Body = $bodyContent;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode(["sent" => false, "message" => "Email could not be sent. <br/>Mailer Error Details - " . $mail->ErrorInfo]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        "sent" => true
    ));
    //echo "<br/><b>Your message has been sent! Thank you for reaching out to me, I will get back to you ASAP.</b>";
}
}
?>
```

[image]
All the time I am seeing a 404 error, which I think is because its unable to access the API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the php server setup like? Are you using apache or some other http server? What port is it running on? What is in the server logs? What is the server config? etc

Comment: @JoshuaCoady, my apologies, I am using Apache through XAMPP, and the server is listening at port 80. I've updated the "url field", but now I am getting Network Error, and in console log I see - "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/contact/. (Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)."

Comment: Well then, as the error says, you need to add "content-type" to the access-control-allow-headers header value that you are sending back from the server in response to this cross-domain request. if you haven't set that header, which it looks like you probably haven't, then you probably need to set it: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "content-type");`. content-type is not one of the headers allowed by default in CORS. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: P.S. don't set allow-origin to * unless you really want the chance for every website (or every website hacked by a script kiddie) in the world to spam your server with cross-domain AJAX requests to your contact form. Set it just to the domain(s) which should actually be able to make the request legitimately.

Comment: Hey, I actually left it aside for a while, but yeah your suggestion works, there were also some variable names I had to set right. And +1 for the allow origin suggested not to set to * Thanks a lot.